# How to hide before click submit and show after click submit

Tags: javascript, html

How to hide this output box before I click submit button and show after I click submit button
[image: http://prntscr.com/73o4uo]

```html
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="login">
        <label for="ids">Total Twitter (<span id="count">0</span>)
        </label>
        <textarea id="ids" class="input-block-level" name="ids" type="text" placeholder="Email:Password" rows="15" onKeyDown="countFakes()" onChange="countFakes()" style="width:60%;height:35%;"></textarea>
        <br><input type="submit" class="button button-submit" name="dot" Value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="panel-body">
    Result of Checker
</div>

<div class="panel-body">Result</div>
```

Comment: Use the visibility CSS property. Or if you don't want it taking up space use the display property with a value of none.

Comment: If you spent one minute of researching you could easily find the answer.

Comment: please show some of your javascript code

Comment: im not using javascript but im using php code http://prntscr.com/73oejf this is result after i check the username and password :D

Comment: Why did you tag javascript if you dont use it ?

Comment: Added image from link